# c++ boost ranges: any_range and transformed adaptor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-range, boost-iterators

I am trying to wrap a boost range that uses the boost transformed adapter into a boost any range, but this does not seem to work. I constructed a minimal example to illustrate.

```
std::vector<int> myInts = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
boost::any_range<double,boost::forward_traversal_tag,double> range =
    myInts | boost::adaptors::transformed( []( int x ) { return static_cast<double>( x ); } );

for ( double x : range )
    std::cout << x << "\n";
```

In release mode, my VS2015 compiler keeps telling me 'returning address of local variable or temporary'. The code also fails to perform correctly when executed. In debug mode everything is fine.

I think that somehow the `any_range` fails to understand that the transformed adaptor returns by value, even though I explicitly set the Reference template parameter to `double` instead of the default `double&`.

What am I doing wrong with the `any_range`? (Using boost 1.64.0)

Comment: If you replace the `boost::any_range` with `auto`, does the error remain?  Just trying to determine if the problem is in the any_range, or if it's something earlier.

Comment: If I replace the `boost::any_range` with `auto` the error is gone. The error only occurs when I use the `boost::any_range` to type erase the transform iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your range declaration to `boost::any_range<const double, boost::forward_traversal_tag, const double>`, as the type deduction system needs to realize your range is read-only.

Comment: Thank you. This does solve the problem when running the code. Strangely enough, though, the compiler warning remains.